# Implementing an interface that has a method returning an interface but getting a not implemented error

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I'm doing some stuff for an AI class but I seem to have some project structure problems. I know this is easier done in Python but I've already done so and I'm doing this in Java because I've got time to kill.

I've got my classes set up like this:

1. I've got 3 interfaces: `ProblemInterface`, `ActionInterface`, `StateInterface`.
2. I have a Search class that calls methods defined in `ProblemInterface` and hence keeps an `ArrayList` of `ProblemInterface`s.
3. I have a `ProblemQ1` class that (tries to) implement the `ProblemInterface`. Other classes `ActionQ1` and `StateQ1` implement their respective interfaces.

   - `class ProblemQ1 implements ProblemInterface`
   - `class ActionQ1 implements ActionInterface`
   - `class StateQ1 implements StateInterface`
4. The `ProblemInterface` defines a method called `actions()` that takes in a `StateInterface` argument and returns an `ArrayList<ActionInterface>`. So, something like:

   - `ArrayList<ActionInterface> actions(StateInterface state);`
5. Hence, my `ProblemQ1` class is trying to define `actions()` by having it take a `StateQ1` argument and have it return an `ArrayList` of `ActionQ1`'s.

   - `public ArrayList<ActionQ1> actions(StateQ1 state)`
6. The `ProblemQ1` class can't be abstract because I have to instantiate it for every problem that I would like to solve.
7. I have to make other `ProblemQN`, `StateQN` and `ActionQN` classes later on, which implement their respective interfaces.

However, I am getting a compiler error that tells me my `ProblemQ1` class has to be abstract or implement a `ProblemInterface` method. From what I'm seeing, it follows the rules of the interface, and I can't see why it wouldn't treat defining `actions()` in `ProblemQ1` as defining the interface.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the actual code.

Comment: I think that you could have simplified your question by excluding the part about the `Search` class that is actually not your direct issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I'm seeing, it follows the rules of the interface, and I
>   can't see why it wouldn't treat defining actions() in ProblemQ1 as
>   defining the interface.

No you changed the parameter type of the method in `ProblemQ1` :

```
public ArrayList<ActionQ1> actions(StateQ1 state)
```

While the interface defines the method like :

```
ArrayList<ActionInterface> actions(StateInterface state);
```

That means that you overload and not override the method.
Annotate the method with `@Override` and you would see that the compiler doesn't consider it as an override.
Note also that the overrided return type is not compatible either.
`ArrayList<ActionQ1>`  is not a subclass of `ArrayList<ActionInterface>`.
But `ArrayList<ActionQ1>`  is a subclass of `ArrayList<? extends ActionInterface>`.

To solve your problem you can introduce generics in the interface :

```
public interface ProblemInterface<T extends StateInterface, U extends ActionInterface>{   
    ArrayList<U> actions(T state);
}
```

And the implementation could be so :

```
public class ProblemQ1 implements ProblemInterface<StateQ1, ActionQ1>{

    public ArrayList<ActionQ1> actions(StateQ1 state){
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I forgot about the @override tag because it's been a while since I really did some Java. And earlier on I was actually wondering how to use generics with interfaces. Guess this answers my question, thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome. I didn't see this other question but I think that it should be indeed help you to understand. Note that generics with interfaces or classes work in the same way.